# SSIS script task - Read from XML file, match text with system variable and output value to user variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, plsqldeveloper, script-task

I am new with SSIS and struggling with Script task. Trying to figure out how to build script for following scenario.

Here is scenario

I have XML file has following data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<environments>   
<environment>  
<name>DEV3WEB</name> 
<databaseservername>DEV3DB.apc.com</databaseservername
<webservername>DEV3WEB.abc.com/</webservername>
<appservername>DEV3APP.abc.com</appservername>
</environment>
<environment>   
<name>DEV3APP</name>
<databaseservername>DEV3DB.abc.com</databaseservername
<webservername>DEV3WEB.abc.com/</webservername
<appservername>DEV3APP.abc.com</appservername>
</environment>
</environments>
```

**I want script task read 'Name' from XML file - match with System variable 'Machine Name' and write output to user variable 'ServerNumber'.

If machine name is DEV3WEB - output will be number '1' and DEV3APP output will be number '2'.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your XML is not valid (missing closing `>`) in several places...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the information like this:

- first create a CTE with *all* `<environment>`-nodes
- Use the derived table in a simple `SELECT` with a normal `WHERE`-clause

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML='<environments>
  <environment>
    <name>DEV3WEB</name>
    <databaseservername>DEV3DB.apc.com</databaseservername>
    <webservername>DEV3WEB.abc.com/</webservername>
    <appservername>DEV3APP.abc.com</appservername>
  </environment>
  <environment>
    <name>DEV3APP</name>
    <databaseservername>DEV3DB.abc.com</databaseservername>
    <webservername>DEV3WEB.abc.com/</webservername>
    <appservername>DEV3APP.abc.com</appservername>
  </environment>
</environments>';

DECLARE @MachineName NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'DEV3APP';
WITH AllEnvironments AS
(
    select env.value('name[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_Name
          ,env.value('databaseservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_DatabaseServername
          ,env.value('webservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_WebServername
          ,env.value('appservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_AppServername
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'environments/environment') AS A(env)
)
SELECT *
FROM AllEnvironments
WHERE Environment_Name=@MachineName;
```

With bigger XML it would be faster to set the filter into `XQuery` to reduce the workload there (Look at the `.nodes()`-function):

```
DECLARE @MachineName NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'DEV3APP';
SELECT   env.value('name[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_Name
        ,env.value('databaseservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_DatabaseServername
        ,env.value('webservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_WebServername
        ,env.value('appservername[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Environment_AppServername
FROM @xml.nodes(N'environments/environment[name=sql:variable("@MachineName")]') AS A(env)
```

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for your help and interest. Situation is I don't have SQL installed in Web and App server. I have to deploy package remotely. 

Is it possible to work with Script task in SSIS?

Comment: @M.Mehta, sorry. don't know this... No experience in this area... Good luck!